# I am a US citizen and my legal residence is in France. Can I open an account with a US online brokerage firm such as e-trade, etc,?

Tags: united-states, investing, online-brokerage, france

I am a US citizen and my legal residence is in France. Can I open an account with a US online brokerage firm such as e-trade, etc.?

Comment: I am not asking a question about a specific product or service. I am asking if American citizens whose tax residence is not in the United States are legally allowed to open accounts with online brokerage firms based in the United States. Please explain why you put my question on hold.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the broker, [IB](https://www.interactivebrokers.com/en/index.php?f=13416) and [Schwab](http://international.schwab.com/public/international/us_investing/us_expat_essentials) still accept expats. Seems that many other US brokers used to accept expats but tighter tax evasion regulations in 2013 increased the administrative burden on US brokers for US citizens living abroad, most brokers apparently didn't want to bother with this and stopped offering accounts to expats.